# Ticks not showing up for a multi-series d3 svg chart

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am unable to get my ticks to show up with my d3 svg line based series plot(the little line that usually shows up on the axis marking points on the x and y axis)

http://plnkr.co/edit/KvJHXM6bjSeEIsZUsXLk?p=preview

I think I maybe missing an option here

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(4)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    var mmdd = d.getMonth() + '/' + d.getDate();
    var time = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
    return mmdd + " "+ time;

  })
  .tickSize(1)
  .tickPadding(8);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .tickSize(1)
  .ticks(6)
  .orient("left")
  .tickPadding(20);
```

I have tried changing a few "tick" parameters but I can't see why my ticks are missing on both the x and y axis.

Any help or pointers is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.tickSize(1)` is causing your ticks to be too hidden (too small), so remove it, and the setting will default to 6.

If you need to make the axis line (`path`) itself thinner (I guess is this was why you were using the tickSize option), better to style with some CSS instead, e.g.

```
.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000000;
}
```

I'd usually suggest also using `shape-rendering: crispEdges;` in the CSS, but that actually causes the axis to be hidden again because of your use of `viewBox`, which seems to be messing up the display a bit here.

Also, it looks like you're drawing each axis twice - once in `drawChart()` and again when you cal; `drawAxis()` at the end of `drawChart`. I suggest removing the first one.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved it. Resolved plunkr incorporating your change - http://plnkr.co/edit/oFDpd6vQ9IizZNxC0GbI?p=preview. I am only drawing the axis once. drawAxis is only called from within drawChart.

Comment: Yes. You are right. It was rendering the axis twice. Thank you again for your help.